# Fluid Particles display percentage affects blender render

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

According to the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/particles/emitter/display.html), the display percentage I set at 1% in the screenshot should not affect the final render, but choosing a higher value results in more visible particles in the final render of my scene, which uses Cycles. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: "but clearly does" and... what happens, not happens?

Comment: Higher value results in more visible particles in final render.